# How can I copy a file from program's resources to a specific location?

Tags: c#, zip

First I tried this code:

```
File.Copy(Properties.Resources.files,"c:/files.zip");
```

But I get this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'string'

After that i tried to add at finish of first argument:

> .ToString()

But it throw this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'System.Byte[]'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As demonstrated by the compiler error that you are receiving, the resource referenced by `Properties.Resources.files` contains a byte array. To write a byte array to a file, use [File.WriteAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\files.zip", Properties.Resources.files);
```

Answer (score -1):

`File.Copy` [takes two strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2) for the arguments. `Properties.Resources.files` is a byte array. You need to pass the path of the file you want to copy.

Comment: You don't need to pass the absolute path.

Comment: Downvoting. The question regards "copying" a file from a program's resources to a file. The answer provided here implies the user wants to copy one file to another file, which is not the intent.